# NGINX: connect() to unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, linux, sockets, nginx, ansible

I'm trying to follow [this Ansible tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-basic-php-application-using-ansible-on-ubuntu-14-04) while adjusting it for Ubuntu 16.04 with php7. Below this message you'll find my Ansible file. After running it and trying to visit the page in the browser I get a 404, and the following in the nginx error logs:

> 2016/10/15 13:13:20 [crit] 28771#28771: *7 connect() to
>   unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
>   while connecting to upstream, client: 93.xxx.xxx.xx, server:
>   95.xx.xx.xx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "95.xx.xx.xx"

So I checked if the socket file exists, and it seems to exist, but `ls` behaves weird:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/run/php
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     5 Oct 15 13:00 php7.0-fpm.pid
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Oct 15 13:00 php7.0-fpm.sock
$ sudo ls -l /var/run/php7
ls: cannot access '/var/run/php7': No such file or directory
$ sudo ls -l /var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock
ls: cannot access '/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock': No such file or directory
```

Why can `ls` find the socket file if I search it by part of the name `php` while it cannot find the socket file when I list more than that `php7` or even the full name `php7.0-fpm.sock`?

And most importantly, how can I make this work with nginx? All tips are welcome!

below I pasted my Ansible file

```
---
- hosts: php
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: install packages
    apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=yes state=latest
    with_items:
      - git
      - mcrypt
      - nginx
      - php-cli
      - php-curl
      - php-fpm
      - php-intl
      - php-json
      - php-mcrypt
      - php-mbstring
      - php-sqlite3
      - php-xml
      - sqlite3

  - name: enable mbstring
    shell: phpenmod mbstring
    notify:
      - restart php7.0-fpm
      - restart nginx

  - name: create /var/www/ directory
    file: dest=/var/www/ state=directory owner=www-data group=www-data mode=0700

  - name: Clone git repository
    git: >
      dest=/var/www/laravel
      repo=https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
      update=no
    become: true
    become_user: www-data
    register: cloned

  - name: install composer
    shell: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    args:
      creates: /usr/local/bin/composer

  - name: composer create-project
    composer: command=create-project working_dir=/var/www/laravel optimize_autoloader=no
    become: true
    become_user: www-data
    when: cloned|changed

  - name: set APP_DEBUG=false
    lineinfile: dest=/var/www/laravel/.env regexp='^APP_DEBUG=' line=APP_DEBUG=false

  - name: set APP_ENV=production
    lineinfile: dest=/var/www/laravel/.env regexp='^APP_ENV=' line=APP_ENV=production

  - name: Configure nginx
    template: src=nginx.conf dest=/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
    notify:
      - restart php5-fpm
      - restart nginx

  handlers:
    - name: restart php7.0-fpm
      service: name=php7.0-fpm state=restarted

    - name: restart nginx
      service: name=nginx state=restarted

    - name: reload nginx
      service: name=nginx state=reloaded
```

Comment: You are listing the contents of the directory with `ls -l /var/run/php`.
Try `ls -l /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Had the same problem.
Solution is very easy.

In nginx conf file you are trying upstreaming to

`unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock`

Correct path is

`unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`

---

There is a mention about this in the [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04)

> Nginx communicates with PHP-FPM using a Unix domain socket. Sockets
>   map to a path on the filesystem, and our PHP 7 installation uses a new
>   path by default:
>
> PHP 5  `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`
>
> PHP 7  `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`

Comment: Nice one ! works for me on Debian 8 + php7.2-fpm. A lot of sites don't use this path and it didn't work.

Comment: check your php socket: `ls /var/run/php*/**.sock` and use this output

Comment: What is "nginx conf file"? Plase complete path file name or regex for it... It is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?

Comment: About @SergioBelevskij `ls`, my showing modern `/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`... use it instead indecated?

Comment: Twice saved me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17):

In Ubuntu 18.04 the problem for me was that it's currently using PHP 7.2, but the sites-available default file has:

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`

Updating the version on that line so that it's the 7.2 instead of 7.0 fixed the issue for me.

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;`

Answer (score 12):

## Check status:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm status
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl status php7.0-fpm
```

## Try with if already running

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl reload php7.0-fpm
```

## Else try with

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm start
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl start php7.0-fpm
```

Comment: Status gave me `Active: failed` for some reason.
I had to run `sudo service php7.2-fpm start` for service to start.
What could put **php** service in _Active: failed_ mode? Not a clue.

Comment: @WojciechJakubas You could check the log and also in the journal

Comment: on centos7 it is `systemctl status php-fpm`

Answer (score 7):

Edit your **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf** file and find the following line:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

And comment it out or replace it with the following:

```
listen = /var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

Answer (score 4):

Answering your first question:

> Why can `ls` find the socket file if I search it by part of the name `php` while it cannot find the socket file when I list more than that `php7` or even the full name `php7.0-fpm.sock`?

Because when you run `sudo ls -l /var/run/php` you are displaying the contents of the `/var/run/php` directory, but when you run `sudo ls -l /var/run/php7` or `sudo ls -l /var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock` you ask for specific files in its parent directory `/var/run` which do not exist.

As for the second question, it does not seem an Ansible problem, but you need to troubleshoot the placement of files considering the above.

Answer (score 4):

In /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

> user  nginx;

If you web server work at user **www-data**  need write

> user  www-data;