# NGINX: connect() to unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, ubuntu-server

I've just recently moved my websites from apache2 to Nginx as my new web server backend. got to love problems aha.

HTML files in the web host director work prior to php files making there way main directory then I received 502 error from nginx

Error message from nginx: SO thought it was code :)

```
>tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

>2018/07/03 15:27:45 [alert] 1275#1275: *48 open socket #3 left in connection 11
>2018/07/03 15:27:45 [alert] 1275#1275: aborting
>2018/07/03 15:27:47 [crit] 4049#4049: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.1, server: a.com, request: "GET /wp/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket:", host: "a.com"
>2018/07/03 15:28:53 [alert] 4049#4049: *1 open socket #3 left in connection 3
>2018/07/03 15:28:53 [alert] 4049#4049: *2 open socket #11 left in connection 4
>2018/07/03 15:28:53 [alert] 4049#4049: aborting
>2018/07/03 15:28:55 [crit] 4170#4170: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.1, server: c.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket:", host: "c.com"
>2018/07/03 15:28:57 [crit] 4170#4170: *6 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.1, server: a.com, request: "GET /wp/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket:", host: "a.com"
>2018/07/03 15:38:27 [crit] 4170#4170: *20 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.1, server: c.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket:", host: "c.com"
>2018/07/03 15:43:59 [crit] 4170#4170: *33 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 80.82.70.118, server: 0.0.0.0:443
>
```

here's my nginx config

```
#
# Note: This file must be loaded before other virtual host config files,
#
# HTTPS
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name a.com www.a.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;
#    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    include /etc/nginx/templates/misc.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/ssl.tmpl;
#    include /etc/nginx/templates/roundcube.tmpl;
#    include /etc/nginx/templates/iredadmin.tmpl;
#    include /etc/nginx/templates/netdata.tmpl;
#    include /etc/nginx/templates/sogo.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/php-catchall.tmpl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
#    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.a.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
#    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.a.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot


 client_max_body_size 100M;


#  location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
 #               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  #      }

location /wp/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php?q=$uri$args;
}


    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }


}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mail.a.com;
    root /var/www/html/mail;
    index index.php index.html;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/misc.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/ssl.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/roundcube.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/iredadmin.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/netdata.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/sogo.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/php-catchall.tmpl;
# ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
#  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.a.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.a.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name c.com www.c.com;
    root /var/www/c.com/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    include /etc/nginx/templates/misc.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/ssl.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/php-catchall.tmpl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/c.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/c.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot



 client_max_body_size 100M;


#  location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
 #               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  #      }

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;
}


    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }


}
```

here is my fpm config

I've already followed this guide to try and fix the error: 
[NGINX: connect() to unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059745/nginx-connect-to-unix-var-run-php7-0-fpm-sock-failed-2-no-such-file-or-dir)

changed listen = /var/run/php/php-fpm.sock to listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can be used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('www' here)
[www]

; Per pool prefix
; It only applies on the following directives:
; - 'access.log'
; - 'slowlog'
; - 'listen' (unixsocket)
; - 'chroot'
; - 'chdir'
; - 'php_values'
; - 'php_admin_values'
; When not set, the global prefix (or /usr) applies instead.
; Note: This directive can also be relative to the global prefix.
; Default Value: none
;prefix = /path/to/pools/$pool

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = www-data
group = www-data

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
;listen = /var/run/php/php-fpm.sock
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
; Set listen(2) backlog.
; Default Value: 511 (-1 on FreeBSD and OpenBSD)
;listen.backlog = 511

; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions.
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
; When POSIX Access Control Lists are supported you can set them using
; these options, value is a comma separated list of user/group names.
; When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored
;listen.acl_users =
;listen.acl_groups =

; List of addresses (IPv4/IPv6) of FastCGI clients which are allowed to connect.
; Equivalent to the FCGI_WEB_SERVER_ADDRS environment variable in the original
; PHP FCGI (5.2.2+). Makes sense only with a tcp listening socket. Each address
; must be separated by a comma. If this value is left blank, connections will be
; accepted from any ip address.
; Default Value: any
;listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the pool processes (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lower priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool processes will inherit the master process priority
;         unless it specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
; process.priority = -19

; Set the process dumpable flag (PR_SET_DUMPABLE prctl) even if the process user
; or group is differrent than the master process user. It allows to create process
; core dump and ptrace the process for the pool user.
; Default Value: no
; process.dumpable = yes

; Choose how the process manager will control the number of child processes.
; Possible Values:
;   static  - a fixed number (pm.max_children) of child processes;
;   dynamic - the number of child processes are set dynamically based on the
;             following directives. With this process management, there will be
;             always at least 1 children.
;             pm.max_children      - the maximum number of children that can
;                                    be alive at the same time.
;             pm.start_servers     - the number of children created on startup.
;             pm.min_spare_servers - the minimum number of children in 'idle'
;                                    state (waiting to process). If the number
;                                    of 'idle' processes is less than this
;                                    number then some children will be created.
;             pm.max_spare_servers - the maximum number of children in 'idle'
;                                    state (waiting to process). If the number
;                                    of 'idle' processes is greater than this
;                                    number then some children will be killed.
;  ondemand - no children are created at startup. Children will be forked when
;             new requests will connect. The following parameter are used:
;             pm.max_children           - the maximum number of children that
;                                         can be alive at the same time.
;             pm.process_idle_timeout   - The number of seconds after which
;                                         an idle process will be killed.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm = dynamic

; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
; maximum number of child processes when pm is set to 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'.
; This value sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be
; served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork.
; Equivalent to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP
; CGI. The below defaults are based on a server without much resources. Don't
; forget to tweak pm.* to fit your needs.
; Note: Used when pm is set to 'static', 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm.max_children = 5

; The number of child processes created on startup.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Default Value: min_spare_servers + (max_spare_servers - min_spare_servers) / 2
pm.start_servers = 2

; The desired minimum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.min_spare_servers = 1

; The desired maximum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
;pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;

; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
;pm.max_requests = 500

; The URI to view the FPM status page. If this value is not set, no URI will be
; recognized as a status page. It shows the following informations:
;   pool                 - the name of the pool;
;   process manager      - static, dynamic or ondemand;
;   start time           - the date and time FPM has started;
;   start since          - number of seconds since FPM has started;
;   accepted conn        - the number of request accepted by the pool;
;   listen queue         - the number of request in the queue of pending
;                          connections (see backlog in listen(2));
;   max listen queue     - the maximum number of requests in the queue
;                          of pending connections since FPM has started;
;   listen queue len     - the size of the socket queue of pending connections;
;   idle processes       - the number of idle processes;
;   active processes     - the number of active processes;
;   total processes      - the number of idle + active processes;
;   max active processes - the maximum number of active processes since FPM
;                          has started;
;   max children reached - number of times, the process limit has been reached,
;                          when pm tries to start more children (works only for
;                          pm 'dynamic' and 'ondemand');
; Value are updated in real time.
; Example output:
;   pool:                 www
;   process manager:      static
;   start time:           01/Jul/2011:17:53:49 +0200
;   start since:          62636
;   accepted conn:        190460
;   listen queue:         0
;   max listen queue:     1
;   listen queue len:     42
;   idle processes:       4
;   active processes:     11
;   total processes:      15
;   max active processes: 12
;   max children reached: 0
;
; By default the status page output is formatted as text/plain. Passing either
; 'html', 'xml' or 'json' in the query string will return the corresponding
; output syntax. Example:
;   http://www.foo.bar/status
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?json
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?html
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?xml
;
; By default the status page only outputs short status. Passing 'full' in the
; query string will also return status for each pool process.
; Example:
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?full
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?json&full
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?html&full
;   http://www.foo.bar/status?xml&full
; The Full status returns for each process:
;   pid                  - the PID of the process;
;   state                - the state of the process (Idle, Running, ...);
;   start time           - the date and time the process has started;
;   start since          - the number of seconds since the process has started;
;   requests             - the number of requests the process has served;
;   request duration     - the duration in µs of the requests;
;   request method       - the request method (GET, POST, ...);
;   request URI          - the request URI with the query string;
;   content length       - the content length of the request (only with POST);
;   user                 - the user (PHP_AUTH_USER) (or '-' if not set);
;   script               - the main script called (or '-' if not set);
;   last request cpu     - the %cpu the last request consumed
;                          it's always 0 if the process is not in Idle state
;                          because CPU calculation is done when the request
;                          processing has terminated;
;   last request memory  - the max amount of memory the last request consumed
;                          it's always 0 if the process is not in Idle state
;                          because memory calculation is done when the request
;                          processing has terminated;
; If the process is in Idle state, then informations are related to the
; last request the process has served. Otherwise informations are related to
; the current request being served.
; Example output:
;   ************************
;   pid:                  31330
;   state:                Running
;   start time:           01/Jul/2011:17:53:49 +0200
;   start since:          63087
;   requests:             12808
;   request duration:     1250261
;   request method:       GET
;   request URI:          /test_mem.php?N=10000
;   content length:       0
;   user:                 -
;   script:               /home/fat/web/docs/php/test_mem.php
;   last request cpu:     0.00
;   last request memory:  0
;
; Note: There is a real-time FPM status monitoring sample web page available
;       It's available in: /usr/share/php/7.2/fpm/status.html
;
; Note: The value must start with a leading slash (/). The value can be
;       anything, but it may not be a good idea to use the .php extension or it
;       may conflict with a real PHP file.
; Default Value: not set
pm.status_path = /status

; The ping URI to call the monitoring page of FPM. If this value is not set, no
; URI will be recognized as a ping page. This could be used to test from outside
; that FPM is alive and responding, or to
; - create a graph of FPM availability (rrd or such);
; - remove a server from a group if it is not responding (load balancing);
; - trigger alerts for the operating team (24/7).
; Note: The value must start with a leading slash (/). The value can be
;       anything, but it may not be a good idea to use the .php extension or it
;       may conflict with a real PHP file.
; Default Value: not set
;ping.path = /ping

; This directive may be used to customize the response of a ping request. The
; response is formatted as text/plain with a 200 response code.
; Default Value: pong
;ping.response = pong

; The access log file
; Default: not set
;access.log = log/$pool.access.log

; The access log format.
; The following syntax is allowed
;  %%: the '%' character
;  %C: %CPU used by the request
;      it can accept the following format:
;      - %{user}C for user CPU only
;      - %{system}C for system CPU only
;      - %{total}C  for user + system CPU (default)
;  %d: time taken to serve the request
;      it can accept the following format:
;      - %{seconds}d (default)
;      - %{miliseconds}d
;      - %{mili}d
;      - %{microseconds}d
;      - %{micro}d
;  %e: an environment variable (same as $_ENV or $_SERVER)
;      it must be associated with embraces to specify the name of the env
;      variable. Some exemples:
;      - server specifics like: %{REQUEST_METHOD}e or %{SERVER_PROTOCOL}e
;      - HTTP headers like: %{HTTP_HOST}e or %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}e
;  %f: script filename
;  %l: content-length of the request (for POST request only)
;  %m: request method
;  %M: peak of memory allocated by PHP
;      it can accept the following format:
;      - %{bytes}M (default)
;      - %{kilobytes}M
;      - %{kilo}M
;      - %{megabytes}M
;      - %{mega}M
;  %n: pool name
;  %o: output header
;      it must be associated with embraces to specify the name of the header:
;      - %{Content-Type}o
;      - %{X-Powered-By}o
;      - %{Transfert-Encoding}o
;      - ....
;  %p: PID of the child that serviced the request
;  %P: PID of the parent of the child that serviced the request
;  %q: the query string
;  %Q: the '?' character if query string exists
;  %r: the request URI (without the query string, see %q and %Q)
;  %R: remote IP address
;  %s: status (response code)
;  %t: server time the request was received
;      it can accept a strftime(3) format:
;      %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z (default)
;      The strftime(3) format must be encapsuled in a %{<strftime_format>}t tag
;      e.g. for a ISO8601 formatted timestring, use: %{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t
;  %T: time the log has been written (the request has finished)
;      it can accept a strftime(3) format:
;      %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z (default)
;      The strftime(3) format must be encapsuled in a %{<strftime_format>}t tag
;      e.g. for a ISO8601 formatted timestring, use: %{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t
;  %u: remote user
;
; Default: "%R - %u %t \"%m %r\" %s"
;access.format = "%R - %u %t \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %f %{mili}d %{kilo}M %C%%"

; The log file for slow requests
; Default Value: not set
; Note: slowlog is mandatory if request_slowlog_timeout is set
;slowlog = log/$pool.log.slow

; The timeout for serving a single request after which a PHP backtrace will be
; dumped to the 'slowlog' file. A value of '0s' means 'off'.
; Available units: s(econds)(default), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Value: 0
;request_slowlog_timeout = 0

; Depth of slow log stack trace.
; Default Value: 20
;request_slowlog_trace_depth = 20

; The timeout for serving a single request after which the worker process will
; be killed. This option should be used when the 'max_execution_time' ini option
; does not stop script execution for some reason. A value of '0' means 'off'.
; Available units: s(econds)(default), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Value: 0
;request_terminate_timeout = 0

; Set open file descriptor rlimit.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Chroot to this directory at the start. This value must be defined as an
; absolute path. When this value is not set, chroot is not used.
; Note: you can prefix with '$prefix' to chroot to the pool prefix or one
; of its subdirectories. If the pool prefix is not set, the global prefix
; will be used instead.
; Note: chrooting is a great security feature and should be used whenever
;       possible. However, all PHP paths will be relative to the chroot
;       (error_log, sessions.save_path, ...).
; Default Value: not set
;chroot =

; Chdir to this directory at the start.
; Note: relative path can be used.
; Default Value: current directory or / when chroot
;chdir = /var/www

; Redirect worker stdout and stderr into main error log. If not set, stdout and
; stderr will be redirected to /dev/null according to FastCGI specs.
; Note: on highloaded environement, this can cause some delay in the page
; process time (several ms).
; Default Value: no
;catch_workers_output = yes

; Clear environment in FPM workers
; Prevents arbitrary environment variables from reaching FPM worker processes
; by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this
; pool configuration are added.
; Setting to "no" will make all environment variables available to PHP code
; via getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER.
; Default Value: yes
;clear_env = no

; Limits the extensions of the main script FPM will allow to parse. This can
; prevent configuration mistakes on the web server side. You should only limit
; FPM to .php extensions to prevent malicious users to use other extensions to
; execute php code.
; Note: set an empty value to allow all extensions.
; Default Value: .php
;security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7

; Pass environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH. All $VARIABLEs are taken from
; the current environment.
; Default Value: clean env
;env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
;env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
;env[TMP] = /tmp
;env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
;env[TEMP] = /tmp

; Additional php.ini defines, specific to this pool of workers. These settings
; overwrite the values previously defined in the php.ini. The directives are the
; same as the PHP SAPI:
;   php_value/php_flag             - you can set classic ini defines which can
;                                    be overwritten from PHP call 'ini_set'.
;   php_admin_value/php_admin_flag - these directives won't be overwritten by
;                                     PHP call 'ini_set'
; For php_*flag, valid values are on, off, 1, 0, true, false, yes or no.

; Defining 'extension' will load the corresponding shared extension from
; extension_dir. Defining 'disable_functions' or 'disable_classes' will not
; overwrite previously defined php.ini values, but will append the new value
; instead.

; Note: path INI options can be relative and will be expanded with the prefix
; (pool, global or /usr)

; Default Value: nothing is defined by default except the values in php.ini and
;                specified at startup with the -d argument
;php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f www@my.domain.com
;php_flag[display_errors] = off
;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
;php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M
```

knowing me I'm missing something in my nginx config.

let me know if you require any additional ls-l or cat of any files thanks :)

Comment: You did the exact opposite of what it told you to do.  The listener in fpm has to match your nginx config...

Comment: No correct answer?

Comment: In my case it was wrong path to fastCGI phpFPM socket file inside nginx file `/location` block. Instead of `unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock;` I had to change to:
`fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;`

Answer (score 85):

first, as the log, your problem is...

you dont have the sock!
the sock (php7.2-fpm----) is made when you start php.

1. check the location to make the sock.

   - go to /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/ -> www.conf
   - you can see the listen = "something something" <-- this is the location address.
   - if it is not /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock, replace it.
2. run php (sudo service php7.2-fpm restart)
3. check the folder you download sock (var/run/php)
4. if you get the sock, restart your nginx
5. if you get error, that means your nginx setting (to find the sock) is wrong.
6. go to etc -> nginx -> sites-enabled and open default
7. if fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; is not, replace them.
8. save and run it.

finish.

Comment: This seems to solution of the problem, but I have no /etc/php folder ?! I have php 7.2 installed as only version of php on my server. I don't know why. How can I fix this?

Comment: For me it was `sudo service php7.2-fpm restart` I forget to `restart/start` it .

Comment: centos 7 `systemctl start php-fpm`

Answer (score 46):

Make sure you have everything properly setup.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-fpm
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

This will generate file `/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`

Comment: If u are running lated `PHP version` e.g `php7.4` then `sudo apt-get install php7.4-fpm` and then `sudo service nginx restart` `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`. Also remember to change the name in the its name in `/etc/nginx/site-enable/example.com` as well

Comment: The kicker for me was the nginx conf with the wrong version. +1 for the logs though - dummy

Comment: Thanks. For me, repeatedly checking `sudo service php7.4-fpm status` and `sudo service nginx status` and `ps -aux` was also helpful.

Comment: your answer saved me many times, every time that happened I reach your answer and it works, but why this happened in the first place? I don't remember purging any files?

Comment: I'm using lighthttpd and a combination of this answer and the comments helped me out.

The server was using the wrong version (7.3) instead of the installed one (7.2) The trick was to point the config to the correct version

/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/15-fastcgi-php.conf

Answer (score 10):

`/var/run/` is probably actually a symlink to `/run/`

`/run/` belongs to root and permissions are 755. php-fpm is running as www-data so can't create a socket in `/run/`

The solution is to create `/run/php/`and change ownership to www-data, then change your socket path to `/run/php/php-fpm.socket`

Comment: so i've made the changes to /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool/www.conf and i've changed my listen line to /run/php/php-fpm.sock; I ls -l the dir /var/run permissions are set to 755 and root as owner, then ls -l the php, its owned by www-data and the files list within are -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     4 Jul  3 17:25 php7.2-fpm.pid & srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jul  3 17:25 php-fpm.sock . when I re run tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: 2018/07/03 17:24:15 [crit] 9607#9607: *20 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.1, server: breakersdrillsamerica.com, request: "GET /wp/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket:", host:

Comment: its still looking into /var/run/php-fpm.socket when i've changed my nginx 00-default-ssl conf to match /run/php/php-fpm.sock

Comment: Have you reloaded Nginx?

Comment: reload or restart? i've been restarting it

Comment: `nginx -s reload` as root. You'll need to restart php-fpm too

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I rebuilt a nginx VM and copy pasted its pool/www.conf file. it worked :) so I might have butchered something.

Answer (score 10):

Reinstall php-fpm works for me:

```
apt-get purge php7.3-fpm
rm -rf /etc/php/7.3/fpm/
apt-get install php7.3-fpm
service nginx restart
service php7.3-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 8):

Check your `php7.x-fpm.sock` file to see what version they are.

Mine was: `php7.0-fpm.sock` instead of `php7.2-fpm.sock`

Don't forget to also change its name in `/etc/nginx/site-enable/example.com`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved a lot of headache and time for newbies to php.

Answer (score 4):

Mine was inside another `php` folder, so:
`/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Php 7.2

Answer (score 3):

A possible explanation, as I just faced: the **disk was full**.

Php-fpm was logging the error, and after a while the php-fpm cgi service did crash and wasn't able to restart, while my server (Caddy) was still online. (Had also a bunch of scripts writing to disc in the same time).

This was leading to the http error `502 Bad Gateway`.

The solution is to leave a large amount of hdd space, empty the trash, empty the apt cache, and else. Make sure to find the cause of the problem, so the issue doesn't come back. Watch your logs time to time.

Then, *on my machine* (use your php-fpm version):

```
/etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm restart
```

[Alternatives way to restart](https://serverfault.com/a/189961)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the only solution that has worked for me is:

First: Check your installed php version `php -v`

Second: check the php-fpm service status to make sure it's the problem
`sudo service php7.4-fpm status` should return not running.

Finally: Start the php fpm service depending on your version of php, for example, for me `php -v` output was PHP 7.4.3. To start the service, run
`sudo service php7.4-fpm start` or `systemctl start php7.4-fpm` if your linux is using systemd.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue, there is lot of error message like

```
connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket failed
```

after restart php-fpm service it works

```
sudo service php8.2-fpm restart
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Following digitalocean In server Confrigation it says php version 7.2

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Check your php7.x-fpm.sock file to see what version they are.

Mine was: php7.4-fpm.sock instead of php7.2-fpm.sock

And  change its name in /etc/nginx/site-enable/example.com

Answer (score 1):

If u are running latest `PHP version`

```
 e.g `php7.4`
```

then `sudo apt-get install php7.4-fpm` 
and then `sudo service nginx restart` `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`. Also remember to change the name in the `/etc/nginx/site-enable/example.com` as well

Answer (score 1):

It's possible php-fpm was killed by your "OOM killer" (system was out of memory.)

Did you commit too much memory?
`cat /proc/meminfo|grep Commit`

Depending how your system is configured, you could lower `max_children` or related settings. The documentation in php-fpm.d/www.conf explains it well.

Hypothetically, if you use the "dynamic" setting, you could spawn too many children and drain all your memory.

Generally speaking, you might need to reconfigure your system. Add more memory and/or take a look at the memory requirements of your database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the listen option in the archive /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf, if you are trying to use something like "listen = 127.0.0.1:9000" put that line to original "listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock", with that option php-fpm works correctly.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

go to /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/ -> www.conf
you can see these two lines above the listen =
Now change these lines

```
user = <yourUserName>
group = www-data
```

restart your nginx

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple versions of php available for nginx to use on demand, you need to enable each version as a service.  Run these commands ONCE and they will persist thru server boot cycles.

```
> sudo systemctl enable php7.1-fpm
> sudo systemctl enable php7.2-fpm
> sudo systemctl enable php7.3-fpm
```

... and so on.  Then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a long research about this 502, socket file missing error. Nothing helped. But then after hours I realized, I've made a mistake. I copied the config file /etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/original.conf to .../copy.conf. In all places also the nginx' site config everything was perfect. But I missed one single line: The first line in /etc/php/8.2/pool.d/copy.conf had the same name in brackets as .../original.conf. It seems php-fpm ignores either the first or the second definitions with the same section name. Or the second one may overwrite the first one. So *that* was the cause in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For me (once again ) it was in `www.conf` after installing php8.2 (from 7.4)
I changed that file as usual (username / group) at the top , but after hours of searching trying I figure put there is second line include this

```
listen.owner = http
listen.group = http
```

Which had to be changed too as the user of Nginx (I'm using www-data)

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

after that Nginx will be able tom communicate with php-fpm