# /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock is missing in Docker-debian container

Tags: php, docker

I'm in a docker container with debian. I have installed nginx and also installed `php-fpm` through `apt update && apt install php-fpm`.

I can confirm php was installed fine and working properly:

```
root@1b6b551h5420:/run# service --status-all
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  nginx
 [ + ]  nginx-debug
 [ - ]  php7.3-fpm
 [ - ]  pro cps
root@1b6b551h5420:/run#
```

However, I cannot find `/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock`; I have checked by `cat /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and I can see the line:

`listen = /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock`

But, in my container, when I go to `/run/`, the folder `php` does not even exist:

```
root@1b6b551h5420:/run# ls
lock  nginx.pid  utmp
root@1b6b551h5420:/run#
```

Am I missing some steps? any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158830/nginx-connect-to-unix-var-run-php7-2-fpm-sock-failed-2-no-such-file-or-dir ?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you *start* php-fpm?

In the same way you need to do `service nginx start` , 
you also have to do `service php7.3-fpm start`.

The socket will be created when you start it.