# connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (ERROR)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 server which is running on Ubuntu. I run my website on this server and it out of nowhere stopped working. When I take a look into my error logs this is the error that keeps showing up. `connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed` Does anyone know how I can fix this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NGINX: connect() to unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059745/nginx-connect-to-unix-var-run-php7-0-fpm-sock-failed-2-no-such-file-or-dir)