# 502 Bad Gateway - Google Cloud Run with php-fpm (socket not found) on cold starts

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, google-cloud-run, fpm

I am dealing with an issue where the first request towards my Google Cloud Run container results in a 502 Bad Gateway error. The following can be seen in the logs:

```
[crit] 23#23: *3 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.8.129, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "my.domain.com"
```

However, on the second request it works fine.

I am using supervisord together with php-fpm and nginx.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

ENV COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT='-1'

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends \
        nginx \
        supervisor \
        libmemcached-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libz-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        openssh-server \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        git \
        cron \
        nano \
        libxml2-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libgmp-dev \
        mariadb-client \
        unzip

RUN docker-php-ext-install exif zip pdo_mysql intl

#####################################
# PHPRedis:
#####################################
RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

#####################################
# Imagick:
#####################################

RUN pecl install imagick && \
    docker-php-ext-enable imagick

#####################################
# PHP Memcached:
#####################################

# Install the php memcached extension
RUN pecl install memcached && docker-php-ext-enable memcached

#####################################
# Composer:
#####################################

# Install composer and add its bin to the PATH.
RUN curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/var/www/vendor/bin" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
# Source the bash
RUN . ~/.bashrc

#####################################
# Laravel Schedule Cron Job:
#####################################

# RUN echo "* * * * * www-data /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1"  >> /etc/cron.d/laravel-scheduler
# RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/laravel-scheduler

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NGINX
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

ADD infrastructure/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
ADD infrastructure/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Move config files
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#

ADD ./infrastructure/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
ADD ./infrastructure/php/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Ensure fpm socket folder is present
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#


RUN mkdir -p /run/php/


RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

COPY ./infrastructure/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN composer install

EXPOSE 8000
```

### entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start the cron service.
service cron start

##
# Run artisan migrate
##

php artisan migrate

##
# Run a command or start supervisord
##

if [ $# -gt 0 ];then
    # If we passed a command, run it
    exec "$@"
else
    # Otherwise start supervisord
    /usr/bin/supervisord
fi
```

### Nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 8000 default_server;

    root /var/www/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name my.domain.com;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    # Remove index.php$
    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php/*(.*)") {
        return 301 $1$2;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffering off;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;
}
```

### phpfpm custom config

```
[global]
daemonize = no

[www]
listen = /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

### supervisord

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g "daemon off;"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Comment: Show how the container is configured and built. Also try changing the socket to **/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock** To confirm, build the container locally, exec into the container, and find the correct socket file path.

Comment: @JohnHanley It works fine locally when I run the container. It's only on google cloud run. However, I will update the answer with more data on how the container is built.

Comment: Is your container responding (listening) on $PORT which defaults to 8080? Check your Nginx configuration.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just updated my question with dockerfile

Comment: Also @JohnHanley it only seems to happen on the first request, i.e. when the Cloud Run is cold started. On requests coming thereafter, it works fine.

Comment: Include the deploy command. Your container is listening on port 8000 which must be specified when deploying the container. Please fix the formatting for **phpfpm custom config**

Comment: Since your application works on the second request, you probably have a race condition. Keep in mind that all the supervisord structure is not necessary. Cloud Run is a Request/Response system. Launching services at each request just slows everything down. They are CPU idled after the response, which means those processes eventually timeout or die.

Comment: @JohnHanley oh, missed that. I've added formatting now. However, there's no such deploy command. What I've provided is basically everything. And yes, I was hoping for a way to avoid Supervisor for the exact reason you say. However, I'd prefer nginx. But using supervisor is the only way I see to have both running in one container. Otherwise I could fallback to apache I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run containers being cold started will need to perform several tasks before being able to serve requests according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#optimizing_performance). This could be the cause of the first request failing, while subsequent requests are served correctly:

> The startup routine consists of:
> starting the service,
> starting the container,
> running the entrypoint command to start your server,
> checking for the open service port

The same documentation page offers several tips to avoid cold starts and improve container startup performance, specially, setting a number of minimum instances that are always idle. Since Cloud Run can scale down to 0 instances, this will create cold starts when there are no instances active.

As for the specific error message from the logs, it seems that a path from your `nginx.conf` file might be wrong according to this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059745/). According to the thread, the path to `fpm` should be:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; //with your specific fpm version
```

Comment: Was this information useful for your issue? In case it can help future users having the same error.